# Attach search function to button (Android)

Tags: java, android

I've made an app which will let the user input a URL, and the app will grab the source code of the webpage and display it. What I'm trying to do now is to create a search function (the user will be able to click "search" and input what they want to find in the text that's been displayed). I've been researching for a few hours and haven't found anything along the lines of what I'm looking for.

The problem I'm having is what function to actually use to get the searching done? I have a database setup and the idea of the app is for the search results to be stored in the database.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set an onClickListener, using your own implementation of onClickListener;

```
View.OnClickListener    _buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // do what you want here
        }
    };
```

and to attach it to the button:

`button.setOnClickListener(_buttonListener);`

[Read more about it here (android documentation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: The problem I'm having is what function to actually use to get the searching done? I have a database setup and the idea of the app is for the search results to be stored in the database.